# Remove duplicates from combobox which is bind to dataset

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, combobox, dataset, datasource

I have a [xml file](http://ideone.com/OnpgJ) in my project. I am reading the file through the below code in to combobox `cbProduct`. The problem is that the `cbProduct` is displaying duplicate text values. How to make them distinct?

I have gone through some [links](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10515527/1577396) but there way of approach is not related to dataset.

I implemented the below code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(@"..\..\stock.xml");
cbProduct.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
cbProduct.DisplayMember = "productname";
```

*optional*: If you have time it will be appreciable if you explain the process because I am new to .net or provide a link atleast to refer (not msdn).

Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(@"..\..\stock.xml");
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true, "productname");
cbProduct.DataSource = dt;
cbProduct.DisplayMember = "productname";
```

Third code line creates a new table which will have distinct values based on productname column. For More read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6.aspx)

This code is [here](http://ideone.com/MxhOW)

Comment: thanks this working. but what if I have more columns. How to solve this problem. I tried this `DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2" ...);` but it is showing dll files from second column. (first column is good).

Comment: I solved this by creating different datatable objects for different columns. I think this is not a correct way of approach.

Comment: well I need some suggestion. I am using the [code something like this](http://ideone.com/oaN6e). without creating data tables. Is it a good approach?

Comment: This is also good. if that datatable(having default values) is not used anywhere again then your code is fine.

Comment: ok thanks...... please check my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12757461/1577396) if you are free

Answer (score 1):

You can bring distinct `values from database` or you can get `distinct values from c# data table` into new c# data table and bind it to dropdown. [How to select distinct value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199176/how-to-select-distinct-values-from-datatable).

Comment: Thankyou for response. I tried this and i getting error. [Here is my code](http://ideone.com/FbFyC). The error is -- "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."