# populate a combobox based on previous combobox selection in XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, c#-4.0, combobox

I am a .net beginner. I am reading a [XML file](http://ideone.com/OnpgJ) and showing it in two comboboxes ie., `cbProduct` and `cbBrandName`

I need to show text in `cbBrandName` with respect to the selected text in `cbProduct`.

I implemented the below code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(@"..\..\stock.xml");

cbProduct.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true, "productname");
cbProduct.DisplayMember = "productname";

cbBrandName.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true, "brandname");
cbBrandName.DisplayMember = "brandname";
```

The above code is showing all the text values in `cbBrandName`. How to make it to show only the text values which are linked to the selected "productname" column of xml file in `cbProduct`.

Please Help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: your code can be shortened to this http://ideone.com/uELC4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ looks much more scary than it is. There's two bits of it being used in Anirudha's answer, which I'll try to explain. The first is `.Select(x=>`. This means "For each thing in the list, replace it with something". The x represents each item in the list.

For example:

```
new string[]{"a", "b", "c"}.Select(x=>x.ToUpper());
```

turns an array of {"a", "b", "c"}, into an array of {"A", "B", "C"}. It's just saying "Take the each thing in the list, and replace it with whatever you get by calling `ToUpper()` on it.

The other bit of LINQ is `.Where(x=>`. That just says "Give me a smaller list which only has things where this statement is true". So

```
new string[]{"a", "b", "c"}.Where(x=>x == "a");
```

will give you a list of {"a"}. Replacing `x == "a"` with `x != "b"` will give you a list of {"a", "c"}. So in the second bit of code, you're saying "before I do that thing where I replace each item with its productname, I want to filter out anything that doesn't match what I want to match. Then I transform what's left."

---

To apply these to the code example, I'll reformat the lines and comment them.

```
// To set the first combo box:
cbProduct.Items.AddRange( // Add everything we produce from this to the cbProduct list
    doc.Descendants("items") // For each thing that represents an "items" tag and it's subtags
    .Select(x=>x.Element("productname").Value) // Transform it by getting the "productname" element and reading it's Value.
    .ToArray<string>()); // Then convert that into a string[].


// To set the second combo box:
string product2Search=cbProduct.SelectedItem.ToString();// get the currently selected value of cbProduct.
cbBrandName.Items.Clear(); //clears all items in cbBrandNamedoc
cbBrandName.Items.AddRange( // Add everything we produce from this to the cbBrandName list
  doc.Descendants("items") // For each thing that represents an "items" tag and it's subtags
  .Where(x=>x.Element("productname").Value==product2Search) // Filter our list to only those things where the productname matches what's currently selected in cbProduct (which we just stored)
  .Select(y=>y.Element("brandname").Value) // Transform it by getting the "brandname" element and reading it's Value.
  .ToArray<string>()); // Then convert that into a string[]
```

Is that helpful?  When I'm coding myself, I like to split long LINQ statements up by putting them on separate lines like this, and then I can just read down the lines: "I get a list WHERE this is true, then SELECT this other thing based on it, and turn it into an ARRAY."

Comment: In which event should i keep this code to run properly. Till now i was doing this in Form_load event, which was not triggering this function for the second time.

Comment: @Mr_Green you need to put `the second combo box linq code` in change event of `cbProduct`..So as soon as you change `cbProduct` `cbBrandName `would be filled with the required data.
Dont forget to **clear** `cbBrandName` items before inserting in it..

Comment: @Anirudha The `product2search` string is in form_load event with a assigned value of first combobox. then how can i call the string value in change event of second combobox? please help

Comment: @Mr_Green - That's why I grouped it the way I did.  You don't put it in form_load, you put it right before you use it in populating the second combo box.

Comment: @Mr_Green put the second part of linq code in the `SelectedIndexChanged`  event of `cbProduct`..

Comment: @Anirudha Thank you this solved the problem. But it invokes a new problem that the values are not distinct ie., cbProduct is showing duplicate values :( (sorry for late response here current was gone for  2 hours)

Comment: @Mr_Green u need 2 `cbBrandNamedoc.Items.Clear();` before inserting items into `cbBrandNamedoc`

Comment: Thank you for your response i got the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12768492/1577396) :)

Answer (score 3):

In **LINQ2XML**

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load(@"..\..\stock.xml");

//put this code in the form_load event
cbProduct.Items.AddRange(doc.Descendants("items").Select(x=>x.Element("productname").Value).ToArray<string>());//adds all products

//put this code in the SelectedIndexChanged event of cbProduct
string product2Search=cbProduct.SelectedItem.ToString();//selected value of cbProduct
cbBrandNamedoc.Items.Clear(); //clears all items in cbBrandNamedoc
cbBrandNamedoc.Items.AddRange(doc.Descendants("items").Where(x=>x.Element("productname").Value==product2Search).Select(y=>y.Element("brandname").Value).ToArray<string>());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried your code but it is showing red scribbles saying that "The best overload method......has some invalid argument"  [here is my code.](http://ideone.com/7yqQj)

Comment: You need to include all these namespaces for his code to workusing `using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;`

Comment: Instead of `ToList()` use `ToArray()`

Comment: It is showing error "Object reference set to an instance of an object" [here is my code](http://ideone.com/lryOh). I saw this error many times but i cant understand it. I hope i am not annoying you :)

Comment: Then before `string product2Search=cbProduct.SelectedItem.ToString();` do `cbProduct.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal sorry I was having lunch. Still showing same error at the same point

Comment: @Mr_Green - Hopefully, that makes it a little less scary and more understandable.

Comment: @Bobson I think you should post this as an answer so that everyone can refer. It looks good as an answer instead of a compressed comment.