# how to populate a combobox based on the previous combobox selection in XML

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, combobox, dataset

This question is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12757461/1577396) where I got answer to use LINQ  which I cant understand. Is there any other way to do this without using LINQ? (I know LINQ is best, but not good to start with by beginners i think)

I want to populate a combobox based on the previous combobox selection (`cbProduct` and `cbBrandName`)

Both comboboxes have values from same [XML file](http://ideone.com/cIYpC).

Before asking here I have gone through many links but there answer is mostly based on LINQ or it is not related to xml.

I tried the below code: (it just assigns values)

```
           DataSet dsBill = new DataSet();
           dsBill.ReadXml(@"..\..\stock.xml");
 /*ERROR*/ cbProduct.DataSource = dsBill.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true, "productname"); 
           cbProduct.DisplayMember = "productname";
```

One more question, this code was working when i have not assigned `name` attribute to xml file and now it is showing Error -- "*Column 'productname' does not belong to underlying table 'items'.*"

Please help

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you change the format of the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the question about adding the `name` attribute, I *think* that you just didn't update your code to support that.  Try this:

```
       DataSet dsBill = new DataSet();
       dsBill.ReadXml(@"..\..\stock.xml");
       cbProduct.DataSource = dsBill.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Product name"); 
       cbProduct.DisplayMember = "Product name";
```

Comment: Thanks for response. aaa whats the difference? anyway i tried your code still it is showing same error. The xml file is attached to my project so it automatically gets updated.

Comment: I just changed `productname` to `Product name`, since I assumed (incorrectly it appears) that the reason it failed was because the name attribute overrode the old name.

Comment: no actually the `name` attribute has value "Product name". If you have anymore suggestions or efforts please feel free to share :)

Comment: This really is a job for LINQ, as per the other answer.  Basic LINQ is not that hard, even for a beginner.   The syntax is strange, but you don't need to understand it to use it.  I'll go add a comment to that answer on the first question.